# How to pass STD_LOGIC signals to entity with STD_LOGIC_VECTOR signals?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus

I'm working on a school project and have the following flip-flop entity:

```
-- define the width-bit flip flop entity
entity flopr is
    generic (width: integer);
    port (clk, reset: in  STD_LOGIC;
          d:          in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(width-1 downto 0);
          q:          out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(width-1 downto 0));
end flopr;

-- define the width-bit flip flop architecture
architecture asynchronous of flopr is
begin
    process(clk, reset) 
    begin
        if reset ='1' then 
            q <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            q <= d;
        end if;
    end process;
end;
```

I need to pass `STD_LOGIC` signals (bits) to`d` and `q` instead of `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` (vectors).

However, if I simply pass them without any kind of conversion then there is a compilation error since the type being passed (`STD_LOGIC`) is not the same as the type in the `flopr` entity (`STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`), even though the size of the `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` is 1.

From a little Googling and experimentation, I came up with this:

```
zeroMFlopr: entity work.flopr generic map(1) port map(clk => clk, reset => reset, d => (0=>zeroE), q(0) => zeroM);
```

Where `zeroE` and `zeroM` are of type `STD_LOGIC`.

It compiles, but is this the correct way to do this?

EDIT: I tried compiling in quartus and as I said it worked fine, but when I try compiling in modelsim I receive the error:

> Actual expression (aggregate) of formal "d" is not globally static.

The error is referencing the line I posted above.

Comment: It looks good to me...

Comment: @KevinCadieux modelsim is giving an error, so I'm not sure this works.. I updated my question with the error. Also, I don't know who downvoted this, but it would be nice to know why. I'm a student trying to learn an extremely unintuitive and confusing language and after a lot of research and multiple attempts asked for help on here. Isn't that what this site is for?

Comment: @Nate: `port map(clk => clk, reset => reset, d(0) => zeroE, q(0) => zeroM)`

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3 Aggregates, 9.3.3.1 "Aggregates containing a single element association shall always be specified using named association in order to distinguish them from parenthesized expressions." `d` and `q` are defined with globally static ranges of the second form (5.2.1), they aren't a nulll range (5.2.1): "The range L to R is called an ascending range; if L > R, then the range is a null range. The range L downto R is called a descending range; if L < R, then the range is a null range."

Answer (score 2):

VHDL-2002 does not allow `d => (0=>zeroE)`, and that is the reason for the:

> Actual expression (aggregate) of formal "d" is not globally static.

VHDL-2008 allows that, so it will work if the tools support that feature of VHDL-2008.

For VHDL-2002 coding style, with named association for generic, write:

```
zeroMFlopr: entity work.flopr 
  generic map(
    width => 1)
  port map(
    clk => clk,
    reset => reset, 
    d(0) => zeroE, 
    q(0) => zeroM);
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3 Port clauses "...the expression shall be one of the following: -The name of an object whose subtype is globally static ... - An aggregate, provided all choices are locally static and all expressions in element associations are expressions described in this list"

Comment: Morten's method is capable of working across any version of the VHDL standard (as are the additional two methods showed in an additional answer).

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two more ways to connect `zeroE` and `zeroM` to formals of an array type in versions of the VHDL standard prior to -2008 besides Morten's use of a sliced formal name:

First, proxy signals:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity flopr_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of flopr_tb is
    constant width: integer := 1;
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal reset:   std_logic := '0';
    signal zeroE:   std_logic;
    signal zeroM:   std_logic;
    signal d:       std_logic_vector (width -1 downto 0);
    signal q:       std_logic_vector (width -1 downto 0);    

begin

    d <= "" & zeroE;
    zeroM <= q(0);
DUT:
    entity work.flopr
        generic map (width)
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            d => d,
            q => q
        );
end architecture;
```

Then there's defining array type signals and using aliases:

```
architecture fum of flopr_tb is
    constant width: integer := 1;
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal reset:   std_logic := '0';
    signal d:       std_logic_vector (width -1 downto 0);
    signal q:       std_logic_vector (width -1 downto 0);   
    alias zeroE is d(0);
    alias zeroM is q(0);

begin

DUT:
    entity work.flopr
        generic map (width)
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            d => d,
            q => q
        );
end architecture;
```